# How long in milliseconds before Android triggers an ANR?

Tags: android, timeout, android-anr-dialog

How long in milliseconds can the main thread be blocked on Android before an ANR is triggered?

Surprisingly I can't seem to find an answer to this.

That tells me that there is no fixed amount, and it probably depends on the device, Android version, and/or runtime circumstances.

Can it simply be found by checking some global variable at runtime?

If not, then, what is the formula/algorithm that Android uses to decide what the time-out length is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ANR will be triggered for your app when one of the following conditions occur:

While your activity is in the foreground, your app has not responded to an input event or BroadcastReceiver (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
While you do not have an activity in the foreground, your BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within a considerable amount of time.

source : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr